# How to Extract numbers from text to a column

Tags: excel

I am new here and I have an Excel 2013 question.

How to extract numbers from one specific character to a column?

The strings are like: `A10 B203 A22 K34 A60 A92 A81 A2` and 
I would like to extract numbers after character `A` in one column
So, the result should be `10,22,60,92,81,2`.

Max repetitions of A is 6. If is possible a Formula for this

Comment: You'll need to know where the character is in the string.  Start by looking at the FIND formula

Comment: What does max repetitions of A is 6 mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a formula to get rid of the first character and your list is in column A, enter this in B1:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="A",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest VBA, but since you have asked for a formula:

1. Apply Text to Columns with space as delimiter. If starting in A1 should populate A1:H1.
2. In J1 and copied across to Q1 (and down as desired):

   `=IF(LEFT(A1)="A",A1,"£")`

(Use `#` or `|` or whatever suits if `£` does not.)

3. Select ColumnsJ:Q Copy and Paste Special..., Values over the top.
4. Select ColumnsJ:Q and replace `A` by nothing, then `£` by nothing.
5. Select ColumnsJ:Q and Go To Special..., Blanks click on one of those selected and Delete... with Shift cells left.
6. In S1 (copied down if required):

   `=LEFT(J1&","&K1&","&L1&","&M1&","&N1&","&O1&","&P1&","&Q1,
      LEN(J1&","&K1&","&L1&","&M1&","&N1&","&O1&","&P1&","&Q1)-8+COUNT(J1:Q1))`

(Beware of a line break if copying the above.)
(TEXTJOIN would be nice but is not available in all Excel versions.)

Should accommodate fewer than eight entries in a 'set' but would need adjustment for more than that.